# How can I use the find all () and () txt methods in the BeautifulSoup library?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want all tags with a bargain price from the link given to the url. find. But when I use the find_all () method
I use and want it as text ()

Show in the for loop, but I have the following output:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://divar.ir/s/tehran/auto'
test_page = requests.get(url)
b = test_page.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(b,'html.parser')

c = soup.find_all('div',attrs="kt-post-card__top-description kt-post-card-description")

for v in c:
    print(v.txt)
```

Please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply find all class attribute by using `c = soup.find_all(class_="kt-post-card__top-description kt-post-card-description")`

The following code will get the result

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://divar.ir/s/tehran/auto'
test_page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(test_page,'html.parser')

c = soup.find_all(class_="kt-post-card__top-description kt-post-card-description")
for i in c:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck to your project :)